# How can I force maple to perform chain differentiation?

Tags: maple, differentiation

When differentiating functions, it is often not clear to me, in which cases maple performs a chain differentiation and when it does not so.

Let's look at an example:

```
f := (x, y) -> r(x)*M(y);
g := (x, y) -> h(x, f(x,y));
A := D[2](g);
```

Then `A(a,b)` gives just

```
D[2](g)(a,b)
```

**Question:** Why does maple not perform the differentiation by going through the definitions applying the chain rule? And how can I get maple to do so?

Even more puzzling, in this simpler example, maple behaves as i wish:

```
f := 'f';
g := (x, y) -> h(x, f(x,y));
A := D[2](g);
```

Then `A(a,b)` returns

```
D[2](h)(a, f(a, b))*D[2](f)(a, b)
```

Maybe this helps to tackle the problem...

Answer (score 1):

Is this useful?

```
restart:

f := (x, y) -> r(x)*M(y):
g := (x, y) -> h(x, f(x,y)):

#diff(g(x,y),y);
#convert(diff(g(x,y),y),D);

unapply(convert(diff(g(x,y),y),D),[x,y]);

              (x, y) -> D[2](h)(x, r(x) M(y)) r(x) D(M)(y)
```

Comment: So the basic trick is to use `convert(diff(g(x,y),y),D)` instead of `D[2](g)(x,y)`, right? 
Thank you! In some sense that does the job, but it's a pain if you want your code function-based. Also the code becomes a pain when I go to more complicated problems. 
Is there hope for a cleaner function-based solution?

Comment: Can please answer similar question on Mapleprime ? http://mapleprimes.com/questions/219357-How-To-Use-ToJet-Command-When-Differential